# Matrix singular values distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, singular-values

As a part of my project I had sliced short B&W video in frames, then denoting each frame as a matrix I reshaped 3D matrix ([frame]x[vertical_pixels]x[horizontal_pixels]) into 2D matrix - [frame]x(vertical_pixels * horizontal_pixels). After that I applied singular value decomposition (SVD) and sorted $\Sigma$ main diagonal elements in descending order. Plotting all that singular values got me a following graph (Log scale): .

And now I'm confused by min/max values being detached from the main trend. Do you have any ideas why it is happening?

EXTRA: It is CCTV recording, the road is being recorder and several people are passing by.

[image]

Comment: Your graph doesn't show the individual values so it is unclear exactly what they are.  It is likely that some singular values are effectively 0 but look nonzero due to round off errors.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, fixed that

Comment: Seems the first several (can't tell from the plot) principal components are picking up most of the activity (maybe repeated structures in the images) followed by variation which gives the plateau.

Comment: @Aruralreader Thanks a lot for your response, and what do you think about minimum values? Moving objects maybe?

Comment: The small values means you've hit the rank of the data set, no more information from the svd, it's already been captured in the other components.

Comment: Without having more background information it will be hard to give a definitive answer, but I think rural reader's idea goes in the right direction.

Comment: @Hyperplane, added more info about video itself..

Comment: So I think you can actually test this hypothesis directly: Compute the low rank approximation and convert it back to a video. Then if the hypothesis is true, we should see a still image for the first couple of singular values - until the jump occurs.

Comment: @Hyperplane, actually that happens indeed, for major singular values (first, first+second) only background is left, while subtraction of this low-rank approximated one from initial frame gives moving object on blank background.